# Copy Colunm from table by its header name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a code to copy the column range of a table in my **Workbook 2** if the headers of this **WB** are the same header of a table I have in **Workbook 1**. What I'm trying to do at the moment is that my macro identifies the headers of **WB1** then compare with **WB2**, and if in **WB2** they are found with the same name in relation to **WB1** it will copy the range of the column. I still haven't worked on the code to paste, because my current code is copying only the last column from **WB2** that has a name similar to a header from **WB1** and not all headers with the same name, and besides that it is literally copying the entire column and not all **data below the header**. Here is my code:

```
Sub TEST_PL() 'wb2 is the Source Workbook and wb1 is the Workbook i will paste the data

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("RAW") 'Sheet from wb1 where i will paste the data copied

Dim xRet As Boolean
xRet = IsWorkBookOpen("combine.xlsx") 'Set variable to check if the wb2 is already open

Dim myWb As Workbook: Set myWb = getWorkBookByName("Relatorio Xml Cofre SIEG - ")
'Gets the full name of the wb2, cuz sometimes it will be
'this name plus a bunch of numbers


    If xRet Then    'Display msg if wb2 is not open
        MsgBox "Planilha do SIEG não esta aberta!", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If


Dim Sh1Cell As Range
Dim Sh2Cell As Range
Dim Sh1Title As Range 'Headers range wb1
Dim Sh2Title As Range 'Headers range wb2

Set Sh1Title = ws.Range("A1:F1")
'Headers from the table wb1

Set Sh2Title = myWb.Sheets("Relátorio de Xml's - Cofre").Range("A3:Q3")
'Headers from wb2, there more header on this sheet but i will use
'the same match from wb1 headers to copy the colunms

For Each Sh1Cell In Sh1Title
    For Each Sh2Cell In Sh2Title
        If Sh1Cell = Sh2Cell Then
        
        Sh2Cell.EntireColumn.Copy
        'First i will only copy the range
        
        'Here i will create the command to paste
        
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The two function im using with this code:

```
Option Explicit

Function getWorkBookByName(SearchStr As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If InStr(1, wb.Name, SearchStr, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set getWorkBookByName = wb
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function IsWorkBookOpen(Name As String) As Boolean
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(Name)
    IsWorkBookOpen = (Not xWb Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables, if they're Excel tables and not just ranges of data can be referenced using `ListObject`.  You can then look at each column heading in one table and copy the data over from the another table where the column headings match.
I've used two tables in the same workbook, but can be updated to look at another workbook.

```
Sub Test()

    'Set references to tables.
    Dim T1 As ListObject
    Set T1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim T2 As ListObject
    Set T2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table2")
    
    'Delete the data rows in the second table.
    If Not T2.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        T2.DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
    
    'Resize the second table to match the first.
    T2.Resize T2.Range.Resize(T1.Range.Rows.Count)

    'Copy data over where the heading in second table matches that in the first.
    Dim listCol As ListColumn
    Dim copyVals As Variant
    For Each listCol In T2.ListColumns
        copyVals = T1.ListColumns(listCol.Name).DataBodyRange.Value
        listCol.DataBodyRange = copyVals
    Next listCol
    
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
This might be better for checking if the workbook is open - it returns True if you or anyone else has it open.

```
Public Function WorkbookIsOpen(FullFilePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim ff As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FullFilePath For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    'Check if the error number is different from 0. i.e. Was an error raised?
    WorkbookIsOpen = (Err.Number <> 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: It worked almost perfectly for my use, but in the worksheet where the data is placed, the empty cells had the following value **#N/D** , and how do I make it copy the formulas from the source worksheet as well?